# Eclipse: auto hide main menu like at IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: eclipse

I want to increase the working space on the screen, like at IDEA.

Inder `Luna` there is no any full screen plugin at Marketplace.

Comment: search stackoverflow with keywords like: hide main menu toolbar status bar etc. you will find few post related to it. If these not answers your question then edit it.

Comment: I not found any answers..